# How to get rid of switch statement in a Factory Method when creation is based on an information passed on runtime

Tags: c#, xml, factory

I'm currently struggling with making a good class factory inside of my solution.
I'm creating a model that will cope with XML documents of a very precise kind.
I've got an abstract class 'TreeElement' that implements shared functionalities and there are many subclasses that inherit from it.

Currently I got stucked with a factory method that contains a big switch statement which I'd like to get rid of, but I'm not sure how to do so.

The main problem is that I don't know what subclass should be used before the runtime, because the information is in the XMLNode's descendant which I have to read from first.

How can it be tackled, so that it doesn't look this way:

```
public ITreeElement CreateProperType(...)
{
        switch (nodeType)
        {
            case "A":
               return new A();
            case "B":
               return new B();
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: there are other options that potentially abstract this away a bit more, for example, a dictionary loaded at startup or construction of your factory, with a string key and some kind of factory delegate, or just a type etc however I would argue that switch statements are not inherently bad - your example here I think is a good place for one. You've abstracted your logic in a single place and there the most appropriate code tool is a switch case - my dictionary example, doesn't really give you any benefit and you could argue makes things less clear.

Answer (score 1):

If, as in your example, the node type is always the class name, then you can use the `Activator` class.

```
return (ITreeElement)Activator.CreateInstance ("AssemblyName","MyNamespace." + nodeType);
```

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks!
Unfortunately the majority of the names are matching, but not all of them.
Nonetheless, if there are no other possibilites, I think that at this stage I could refactor the code to match the names entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class for each ITreeElement type that can tell the factory which nodeType it can handle and also can create the type. Something like this

```
interface ITreeElementCreator
{
    string HandlesNodeType { get; }
    ITreeElement CreateTreeElement();
}
```

Then you can implement one for A and one for B like this

```
class ACreator : ITreeElementCreator
{
    public string HandlesNodeType => "A";

    public ITreeElement CreateTreeElement()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

class BCreator : ITreeElementCreator
{
    public string HandlesNodeType => "B";

    public ITreeElement CreateTreeElement()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Then you can let your factory get a list of all `ITreeElementCreator` implementations from your IoC container and then it can find the correct creator and ask it to give you the `ITreeElement` like this

```
class TreeElementFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ITreeElementCreator> treeElementCreators;

    public TreeElementFactory(IEnumerable<ITreeElementCreator> treeElementCreators)
    {
        this.treeElementCreators = treeElementCreators;
    }

    public ITreeElement CreateProperType(string nodeType)
    {
        return treeElementCreators.SingleOrDefault(te => te.HandlesNodeType == nodeType).CreateTreeElement() ?? throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown nodeType {nodeType}");
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that you can add new types of `ITreeElement` without changing the factory.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use a dictionary of nodetypes and corresponding functions that can create the types like this

```
class TreeElementFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<ITreeElement>> creatorFuncs = new Dictionary<string, Func<ITreeElement>>
    {
        { "A", () => new A() },
        { "B", () => new B() }
    };

    public static ITreeElement CreateProperType(string nodeType)
    {
        if (!creatorFuncs.TryGetValue(nodeType, out var creatorFunc))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown nodetype {nodeType}");
        return creatorFunc();
    }
}
```